# Manually increase values on y axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to manually set the range of Y axis. I want manually increase values of Y axis by 30 units. I have a following code:

```
library(scales)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars,aes(x=wt,y=mpg)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth() +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = ~.+30)
```

But I got the following **error message**:

> ```
> Error in match.fun(f) : 
>   'c("~_trans", ". + 30_trans")' is not a function, character or symbol
> ```

Can somebody help me?

This is the plot what I want:[image]

Comment: This? https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/lims.html

Comment: Why not simply adding 30 to mpg, i.e. `ggplot(mtcars,aes(x=wt,y=mpg + 30)) + ...` if your goal is to shift the line upwards?

Comment: @R.Schifini No, I do not want to change range of Y axis by using function ylim, but I want to manually increase all values on the Y axis (such as, if you use a logarithmic transformation)

Comment: @stefan Thank You, it is working, but I want to create more complex graph (barplot with more columns, two Y axis etc.) therefore Your result is not suitable in my case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to change the labels, then this will do it.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt,y=mpg)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels=function(x) x+30)
```